# Method 'UIKit.UIApplication.Main' is obsolete: Use the overload with 'Type' instead of 'String' parameters for type safety

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

After upgrade my Xamarin.Forms version to 5.0.0.2244, I'm getting the following warning in `Main.cs` file inside my iOS project:

> Method `UIKit.UIApplication.Main` is obsolete: Use the overload with `Type` instead of `String` parameters for type safety.

This my `Main.cs` file:

```cs
using UIKit;

namespace LindeGctMobileApplication.iOS
{
    public class Application
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate"); // << warning
        }
    }
}
```

What do I need to change to remove this warning?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Class reference through a string is now deprecated. You need to change this line:

```cs
UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
```

to this:

```cs
UIApplication.Main(args, null, typeof(AppDelegate));
```

In that way, you explicitly inform the type of the class.

Comment: As a hint: If I use the new approach the app crashes, when taking a picture with the `CrossMedia` plugin. The exception is: *There's no current active window (System.InvalidOperationException)*

Comment: This is a good bug to investigate. Do you know why?

Comment: The plugin is not maintaned anymore ... One should use the one from Xamarin.Essentials. I didn't investigate more into this.